# Why does Hadoop follow WORM( write once read many times) and does not allow updates?

Tags: hadoop, bigdata

Hadoop follows WORM (write once read many times). Why does it not allow any updates?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question really is what is the motivation for updating data? We store our entities in the database and update them as new information is seen, but why? The reason is that when it was first being architected, disk space was expensive. Fast-forward to present day and disk space is cheap, which means that we can afford to reflect changes to data as new entries, like a log of the changes that the entities go through in their lifespan.

By using this approach, the lineage of the data is more apparent - we simply revisit older versions of the same entity to discover where it has come from and what transformations have been applied to it. Moreover, if something were to happen to the latest version, all is not lost. We simply drop back to an older version and state loss is minimal. This is obviously preferable to updated entities, in which entire entities can be lost and potentially never recovered.

This is documented very well in Nathan Marz and James Warren's ['Big Data - Principles and Practices of Scalable Real-time Data Systems'](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Big-Data-Principles-practices-scalable/dp/1617290343).

Answer (score 1):

It was easier. More precisely, for reliable writes in a distributed cluster with complex failure patterns, significantly easier. And, with applications that are written for append-only/log based operations, works well.

You can now append to HDFS (Hadoop 2.6+ recommended), but you can only write exactly at the end of the file; you can't seek() to earlier in the file, or past the current EOF, then write.

Will this ever be fixed? Maybe. But recent work on encryption at rest and erasure coding has focused more on compressing and encrypting the existing data, which could potentially make seek+write even harder. I'd recommend not waiting for this feature, but writing code which works within the constraints (as HBase and accumulo do).

Comment: I would also add two points: **(1)** When you modify a block, it may grow beyond the block size. That means it would have to be split into two or more blocks, the NameNode metadata would have to be updated and the replicas modified accordingly. **(2)** Hadoop was designed for large scale processing, i.e. you usually read a large amount of data, process it and save the results. You should rarely have a need to modify the files at rest.